# How manage user sessions for unregistered users

Tags: objective-c, swift

How do you handle user sessions for unregistered users.

For example Yik Yak allows anonymous(unregistered) users to vote up/down once.

How do you only allow one vote to be cast when a user isn't logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to store any value is the persistant storage in ios.It will be available even after restarting of app.You can store some values after user cast his/her vote.Using persistant storage you dont need to signup/signin user.But you can still differentiate between users who casted the vote or who doesn't.

> **Swift code**

```
 if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("vote") == nil)
 {
 //user is allowed to cast vote
 // After vote casting just write these below lines 
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("vote casted", forKey: "vote")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
  }
else
 {
// This user already cast vote
// You can now show here some alert message to user that you already voted once etc
 }
```