# How can I prevent user from clicking the button twice? Parse Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

Hi I am making a app that basically updates users on what events are going on in the city, I have it hooked up to parse, so i am able to post new events from parse and if a user clicks "go to this event" i receive the user's info in parse, the only problem I am running into is I don't want the user to be able to click the "go to this event" twice. can someone please help me with preventing user from clicking the button twice. when the user click the button first it takes him to "thank you" view controller, and if the user clicks second time i want to basically say "you are already going to this event"

this is what I am doing to get user's info in parse:

```
        /////// GO TO THE EVENT BUTTON
        @IBAction func Going(sender: AnyObject) {

            let sweet:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Going")
            sweet["userprofile"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            sweet["first_name"] = PFUser.currentUser()?["first_name"] as? String
            sweet["last_name"] = PFUser.currentUser()?["last_name"] as? String
            sweet["email"] = PFUser.currentUser()?["email"] as? String
            sweet["club"] = club.text
            sweet["date"] = date.text
            sweet["eventdetails"] = eventdetails.text
```

I think that it will have to do something with the userprofileID, so that if the same ID click the Button with EVENTDETAILS"------" (because event details would define the events the most i think and would make it unique) to show the view controller "You are already going to this event"

I am using swift 2 Xcode 7

I am new to programming, I hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an outlet for the button besides the IBAction that you already created

```
@IBOutlet var login: UIButton! // rename it to whatever you want
```

[image]

```
@IBAction func Going(sender: AnyObject) {
  // For disabling button
   self.login.enabled = false // disable it on click of the button.Change it to true for enabling

// Now write your other code below
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested and i get this error:

2015-10-11 21:25:10.909 "appname"[52555:4654020] -["appname" Going:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bea2940

2015-10-11 21:25:10.914 "appname"[52555:4654020] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-["appname.DetailViewController Going:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bea2940'
*** First throw call stack:

what do you think is the issue?

Comment: I tested it first and then post here works for me.i am using xcode 7 and swift 2 as well.You should select TouchUpInside outlet for the button which you want to disable

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, is this how it is supposed to be: http://postimg.org/image/9iqc2oz4b/
http://postimg.org/image/uu1tmcvbp/

Im using Xcode 7 and Swift 2,
I am very new to coding maybe I messed up

Comment: yes weak is also fine.add the code inside going method/IBAction

Comment: You mean this code: @IBOutlet var login: UIButton!  
 self.login.enabled = false 

 inside going method/IBAction or which one?

Comment: just add this "self.login.enabled = false" nothing else

Comment: now i get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) 
and it points out red on         self.login.enabled = false
damn it!
idk what to do

Comment: actually it worked now, thanks a lot I really really appreciate it

Comment: do you know i can send it to another view controller on a second click, where it will say "you are already going to this event"
and i promise thats it i won't bother you

Comment: Add a segue from button to another view controller

Comment: I did but now it only takes straight to the one I added

Comment: when i try to add segue the other segue gets erased and i only have one segue

Comment: add a separate question and add code for both view controllers and post the link here

Comment: Ah Im stuck at that, Ill try to figure it out. Btw how can i save the user that clicked the button, because it works first time but when I open the app again it lets me click the button again.

Comment: you need to store it in persistant storage
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231760/how-manage-user-sessions-for-unregistered-users/28235588#28235588

Comment: so I should write:  if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("vote") == nil)
 {
 //user is allowed to cast vote
 // After vote casting just write these below lines 
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("vote casted", forKey: "vote")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
  }
else
 {
// This user already cast vote
// You can now show here some alert message to user that you already voted once etc
 }

this code in the same view controller.

Comment: I know this might be very stupid question but Im really new to it all

Comment: That's not the way Stackoverflow works ..add separate questions and also learn by your self.not asking everything.Test and learn :)